# Many to Many Relationships with Postgres COPY Command

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

Is it possible to include many-to-many relationships when running a Postgres `COPY` command?  If so, can you give me an example?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE "lap" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "Lap_number" integer,
    "Lap_time" interval,
)
;
CREATE TABLE "datasinglerace_Laps" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "datasinglerace_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "lap_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "lap" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    UNIQUE ("datasinglerace_id", "lap_id")
)
;
CREATE TABLE "datasinglerace" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "Notes" text,
)
;
ALTER TABLE "datasinglerace_Laps" ADD CONSTRAINT "datasinglerace_id_refs_id_620382df" FOREIGN KEY ("datasinglerace_id")
  REFERENCES "datasinglerace" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

The lap objects are already in the db.  For the `COPY` file, I'd like to put the  info for the `datasinglerace` `id`'s and a list of the lap object's `id`'s I want to attach.  There will be a variable number of lap objects I want to attach.

This SQL was created with the Django framework.  I want to keep this in the Django framework so I don't want to change the SQL.  Importing the data has been really slow, so I'm working on improving the import data speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COPY` to improve the speed for importaing batches of data once off - I wouldn't use it normally - have you isolated the bottle neck? What are you copying from? You would need something like CSV files with the same structure as the tables..

`COPY` copies directly to PostgreSQL it has nothing to do with Django so you will need interact with Postgres using pgsql or whatever tool you use. Your command will look like this:

```
COPY datasinglerace FROM datasinglerace.csv;
COPY datasinglerace_Laps FROM datasinglerace_Laps.csv;
```

`COPY` has many options see the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html).

Note anything that is referenced by something else needs to be added first otherwise you would need to relax (delete then add back) your reference constraints. In this case you would need to `COPY` datasinglerace_Laps last so the references it has already exist

Comment: I'm processing data and importing into the db.  The bottle neck is the importing speed due to the huge dataset.  I'm currently using the Postgres COPY command.  I'm doing one COPY where I create datasinglerace and another COPY where I fill in the table datasinglerace_Laps with the references to the lap row and the datasinglerace row.  I suspect a performance improvement if I can use the COPY command to create the datasinglerace and fill in the m2m to the lap models at the same time.

Comment: I mentioned Django because changing how the data is modeled isn't something I'm considering at this point unless it fits within the Django ORM.  This is a pure Postgres problem.

Comment: So whats the problem, just doing the COPY in the right order and should work right?

Comment: It works but it is too slow.  I need to improve the import time.